# Return available item by Dates

Tags: php, sql, symfony

My goal:
I want it to return all the rooms that are available on the dates selected by the user.

What I have there:
Quite the opposite, my function return only the rooms where dates are not available.

Example: if a reservation is made for room 1 for the period 01/01/2022 - 02/01/2022, then if the user enters these dates, this room will be returned to him. And nothing is displayed if no date reserved for that day.
I need to do the reverse.

My call:

```
        $rooms = $roomRepository->findByAvailableBookings($start, $leave);
```

My function:

```
public function findByAvailableBookings($start, $leave)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->join('r.bookings', 'b')
        ->where('b.startDate <= :startDate ')
        ->andWhere('b.leaveDate >= :leaveDate')
        ->orWhere('b.startDate >= :startDate')
        ->andWhere('b.leaveDate <= :leaveDate')
        ->orWhere('b.startDate >= :startDate')
        ->andWhere('b.leaveDate >= :leaveDate')
        ->andWhere('b.startDate <= :leaveDate')

        ->orWhere('b.startDate <= :startDate')
        ->andWhere('b.leaveDate <= :leaveDate')
        ->andWhere('b.leaveDate >= :startDate')


        ->setParameter('startDate', $start)
        ->setParameter('leaveDate', $leave);


    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `$qb->exp()->not($qb->between('field', 'from', 'to')`

Comment: Thank you that's very kind, I really appreciate it, but could I have a little explanation with it to understand what I'm doing and not do a simple copy and paste. thanks again.

Comment: this is how you could express `NOT BETWEEN` this is what you want i guess, to chain it it may look like `$qb->add('where', $qb->exp()->not($qb->between('b.startDate', ':startDate', ':leaveDate')->add('where', $qb->exp()->not($qb->between('b.leaveDate', ':startDate', ':leaveDate')`  which should check that b.start and b.end is not between start  and end. I´m just commenting to point u in the right direction

Comment: no, in fact at the beginning the function returned me only the apartments having reservations on the dates selected by the user. I just wanted everything the other way around. Someone told me about NOT IN. I I create a new ticket with my new code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233463/dql-almost-ready-to-go-please-help-me But I can't do it yet. but it looks like your code, except there is no beetween.

Comment: But thank you anyway, it will be useful to me at some point that too! :)